# Node JS Global Variables is not working after call

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, fastify

I'm trying to call my global variables in my controller but i got an error variable is not defined. Please see the code below for your reference. Hoping to solve  my problem. Thank you  Guys

**server.js **

```
const serverConfig = require('./config/server.config')
const app = require('fastify')({ logger: true })
require('./models/response.model')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const conn = require('./config/monggo.config')
require('./routes/dbm.routes')(app)
const connect = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(conn.uri)
        console.log('Connected to Mongoose!')
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

connect();
app.listen(serverConfig.port, '::', (err, address) => {
    if (err) {
        app.log.error(err)
        process.exit(1)
    }
    console.log('Listening at', address)
})
```

**response.model.js**

```
module.exports = function () {

    global.successModel = {
        status: 'sucess',
        statusCode: 0,
        isSuccess: true,
        message: ''
    }
    global.failModel = {
        status: 'failed',
        statusCode: 1,
        isSuccess: false,
        message: 'Error encountered while processing request.'
    }
}
```

**monggo.controller.js
**

```
exports.getProducts = async (req, res) => {
    //find Products in the databse
    Product.find({}, (err, product) => {
        //send error message if not found
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }
        //else pass the Products
       
        res.send(successModel);
    })
    await res;
}
```

Hoping to solve my problem. Thank you

Comment: Which global variable?

Answer (score 0):

The `'./models/response.model'` file exports a function that you need to call to "install" your globals.

```
- require('./models/response.model')
+ require('./models/response.model')()
```

As a suggestion, you should avoid to use globals, in fastify you can use:

- [decorator](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Reference/Decorators/#decoratename-value-dependencies) to add to your `app` instance useful data such as `config`s

Moreover, your mongoose connection is unrelated with Fastify, you can encapsulate it into a plugin to be sure that fastify is starting after connecting to the database:

```js
const fp = require('fastify-plugin')
app.register(fp(async function connect (instance, opts) {
  await mongoose.connect(conn.uri)
}))
```